# Evolution hanging after ubuntu 22.10 upgrade

Tags: evolution

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 from 22.04 evolution is now hanging everytime I try to compose a new, or reply to an email.
The program freezes and I have to right click the icon to quit it.
Its downloading emails from the server fine, but crashes everytime i try to reply to something.  It doesn't even bring up the new email window.
Ive upgraded to version 3.46.0 of evolution, and the error still remains.

I could really do with some help on this one, so thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Warren